# Unfavoriting jobs gave wrong count

Tags: bug

After review my favorites jobs list and remove some, I realized that the count in the right column was increasing instead of going down

[image]

In the image we can count 5 jobs, and in the right it say 7.

Also, if we are in the favorites view, why to show the favorites jobs section in the right column? isn't redundant?